# pg-promise reads integers as string, even after being parsed

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I'm having the following error:

I have a post form to insert some values to a postgres database using pg-promise. Those values are being converted to integers on the server. But when I try to insert the values to postgres, it says:

```
 invalid input syntax for integer: ""
```

What I'm trying to do:

Every field that its left blank, convert it to NULL and insert it to the database, here's the code:

```
var tier_1 = parseInt(req.body.tier_1);

if (isNaN(tier_1)) {
  console.log("Not a Number");
  tier_1= null;
}
```

and the query:

```
  "insert into products(tier_1) values (${tier_1})"
```

but postgres still reads tier_1 as a string.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Log the actual query you are executing, and then see what your app is doing wrong. For logging query you can use [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor), or event [query](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:query), or [as.format](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/formatting.html#.format) method.

Comment: Hi @vitaly-t, figured it out. It has to do with how javascript/express does the post. Thank you!